# Does the scala fsc ant task simply not work in scala v2.9.1-1?

Tags: scala, ant, fsc

I've looked at this page https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-5196. It looks like it's fixed in v2.10.x. Has anybody gotten the fsc ant task to work in scala v2.9.1-1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you upgrade to 2.10. I don't think there is a workaround.